# Remove outlier rows by column and factor in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filtering, outliers

I am working with a data-frame in R. I have the following function which removes all rows of a data-frame `df` where, for a specified column index/attribute, the value at that row is outside mean (of column) plus or minus n*stdev (of column).

```
remove_outliers <- function(df,attr,n){
  outliersgone <- df[df[,attr]<=(mean(df[,attr],na.rm=TRUE)+n*sd(df[,attr],na.rm=TRUE)) & df[,attr]>=(mean(df[,attr],na.rm=TRUE)-n*sd(df[,attr],na.rm=TRUE)),]
  return(outliersgone)
}
```

There are two parts to my question.

(1) My data-frame `df` also has a column 'Group', which specifies a class label. I would like to be able to remove outliers according to mean and standard deviation *within their group* within the column, i.e. organised by factor (within the column). So you would remove from the data-frame a row labelled with group A if, in the specified column/attribute, the value at that row is outside mean (of group A rows in that column) plus/minus n*stdev (of group A rows in that column). And the same for groups B, C, D, E, F, etc.

How can I do this? (Preferably using only base R and dplyr.) I have tried to use `df %>% group_by(Group)` followed by `mutate` but I'm not sure what to pass to mutate, given my function `remove_outliers` seems to require the whole data-frame to be passed into it (so it can return the whole data-frame with rows only *removed* based on the chosen attribute `attr`).

I am open to hearing suggestions for changing the function `remove_outliers` as well, as long as they also return the whole data-frame as explained. I'd prefer solutions that avoid loops if possible (unless inevitable and no more efficient method presents itself in base R / dplyr).

(2) Is there a straightforward way I could combine outlier considerations across multiple columns? e.g. remove from the dataframe `df` those rows which are outliers wrt at least $N$ attributes out of a specified vector of attributes/column indices (length≥N). or a more complex condition like, remove from the dataframe `df` those rows which are outliers wrt Attribute 1 **and** at least 2 of Attributes 2,4,6,8.

(Ideally the definition of outlier would again be within-group within column, as specified in question 1 above, but a solution working in terms of just within column without considering the groups would also be useful for me.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok - part 1 (and trying to avoid loops wherever possible):

Here's some test data:

```
test_data=data.frame(
    group=c(rep("a",100),rep("b",100)),
    value=rnorm(200)
)
```

We'll find the groups:

```
groups=levels(test_data[,1]) # or unique(test_data[,1]) if it isn't a factor
```

And we'll calculate the outlier limits (here I'm specifying only 1 sd) - sorry for the loop, but it's only over the groups, not the data:

```
outlier_sds=1
outlier_limits=sapply(groups,function(g) {
    m=mean(test_data[test_data[,1]==g,2])
    s=sd(test_data[test_data[,1]==g,2])
    return(c(m-outlier_sds*s,m+outlier_sds*s))
})
```

So we can define the limits for each row of `test_data`:

```
test_data_limits=outlier_limits[,test_data[,1]]
```

And use this to determine the outliers:

```
outliers=test_data[,2]<test_data_limits[1,] | test_data[,2]>test_data_limits[2,]
```

(or, combining those last steps):

```
outliers=test_data[,2]<outlier_limits[1,test_data[,1]] | test_data[,2]>outlier_limits[2,test_data[,1]]
```

Finally:

```
test_data_without_outliers=test_data[!outliers,]
```

EDIT: now part 2 (apply part 1 with a loop over all the columns in the data):

Some test data with more than one column of values:

```
test_data2=data.frame(
    group=c(rep("a",100),rep("b",100)),
    value1=rnorm(200),
    value2=2*rnorm(200),
    value3=3*rnorm(200)
)
```

Combine all the steps of part 1 into a new function `find_outliers` that returns a logical vector indicating whether any value is an outlier for its respective column & group:

```
find_outliers = function(values,n_sds,groups) {
    group_names=levels(groups)
    outlier_limits=sapply(group_names,function(g) {
        m=mean(values[groups==g])
        s=sd(values[groups==g])
        return(c(m-n_sds*s,m+n_sds*s))
    })
    return(values < outlier_limits[1,groups] | values > outlier_limits[2,groups])
}
```

And then apply this function to each of the data columns:

```
test_groups=test_data2[,1]
test_data_outliers=apply(test_data2[,-1],2,function(d) find_outliers(values=d,n_sds=1,groups=test_groups))
```

The `rowSums` of `test_data_outliers` indicate how many times each row is considered an 'outlier' in the various columns, with respect to its own group:

```
rowSums(test_data_outliers)
```